# Save YAML log build into a file?

Tags: git, github, yaml

I have a functional YAML in my GitHub repository and I was wondering how can we save the build log file after the Action is done?

For instance, I have a file `compilation.yml` that only runs `make` (the structure is good, the Action passes well). I would like to save the Action Build log into a new file in my repository.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

`make > newFile.txt`

Can you guys help me please!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download the entire action's log as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/managing-workflow-runs/using-workflow-run-logs#downloading-logs).

There is no way to do this using the action itself at the time of writing. Alternatively, you can run your own program that uses the GitHub REST API and [get a workflow run](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#get-a-workflow-run). You'll then get be able to download the log and push it with `git`.